# How a positive value becomes negative after casting byte in Java?

Tags: java, casting

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        byte b1=40;
        byte b=(byte) 128;

        System.out.println(b1);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

the output is

> 40
>   -128

the first output is 40 I understood but the second output -128 How it is possible ? is it possible due to it exceeds its range ? if yes how it works after byte casting...help me

Comment: overflow max value is 127

Comment: This question is slightly similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121947/is-there-an-explanation-for-the-behavior-of-this-java-bytebuffer).

Comment: [Sign extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension), plus `Byte.MAX_VALUE` is 127.

Answer (score 12):

When you cast 128 (`10000000` in binary) to an eight-bit `byte` type, the sign bit gets set to `1`, so the number becomes interpreted as negative. Java uses [Two's Complement representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), so `10000000` is `-128` - the smallest negative number representable with 8 bits.

Under this interpretation, `129` becomes `-127`, `130` becomes `-126`, and so on, all the way to `255` (`11111111` in binary), which becomes `-1`.

Comment: For further explanation, the leading bit will become the sign of your integer value.

Answer (score 0):

A byte in Java is represented in 8-bit two's complement format. If you have an int that is in the range `128 - 255` and you cast it to a `byte`, then it will become a byte with a negative value (between -1 and -128).

That being said, you should probably **avoid using byte** because there are issues with them. You'll notice if you cast the result to byte, since the operators actually return int. You should just stick to int and long in java since they are implemented better.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with byte as you have stated. The user should know what is range of input and as per that appropriate placeholder should be selected.